# Mysql - Join two tables after group by

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I have two tables in the following structure:

```
Table - a
datetime            | camapgin_id | country | unique_id
2013-12-23 10:23:59 |     123     |    US   |  5475642385763


Table - b
datetime            | camapgin_id | country | unique_id
2013-12-23 10:40:35 |     123     |    US   |  5475642385763
```

I would like to have a query to generate a table like the following:

```
Table - joined
day        | camapgin_id | country | count(1) from a | count(1) from b
2013-12-23 |     123     |    US   |       100       |      82
```

I can generate each table with its own query like this:

```
SELECT date_format(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') AS day, campaign_id, country, count(1)
FROM a
GROUP BY day, campaign_id, country
```

And the same for table b, but this gets me to two distinct tables.

How can i join the two tables by the same `group by` as in the query i posted?

Comment: I don't understand `count(1) from a/b`

Comment: I want to count the rows that are in the group by, so count(1) for each row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(A.day, '%Y-%m-%d') AS day, A.campaign_id, A.country, MAX(tableACount), MAX(tableBCount)
FROM (SELECT DATE(datetime) AS day, campaign_id, country, COUNT(1) tableACount
      FROM a GROUP BY day, campaign_id, country
     ) AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT DATE(datetime) AS day, campaign_id, country, COUNT(1) tableBCount
            FROM b GROUP BY day, campaign_id, country
           ) AS B ON A.day = B.day AND A.campaign_id = B.campaign_id AND A.country = B.country
GROUP BY A.day, A.campaign_id, A.country
```

**EDIT::**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(A.day, '%Y-%m-%d') AS DAY, A.campaign_id, A.country, MAX(tableACount), MAX(tableBCount)
FROM (SELECT DATE(DATETIME) AS DAY, campaign_id, country, COUNT(1) tableACount, 0 AS tableBCount
      FROM a GROUP BY DAY, campaign_id, country
      UNION 
      SELECT DATE(DATETIME) AS DAY, campaign_id, country, 0 AS tableACount, COUNT(1) tableBCount
      FROM b GROUP BY DAY, campaign_id, country
     ) AS A
GROUP BY A.day, A.campaign_id, A.country
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the trick.
What will happen if i have rows in table B that don't exist in table A? Can i somehow show them as 0 in the column of table A?
I think that now they will be hidden

Comment: Also, is this the optimized way to do it?

Comment: @DeaglinG Check my updated answer it will retuns records either the row exist in table A or in table B

Comment: To show columns that are null in table B, just use `left join` in the first answer!